# API Service Architecture vs Browser - Using Workers and Queues

Tags: api, architecture, request, backgroundworker, task-queue

I'm reading [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing#approach) on Heroku about the proper architecture of handling requests and using polling on the browser side if the requests will take longer than a few milliseconds. It is clear and makes sense.

[image]

---

My issue is, I'm in the planning stage of a commercial API service, which *is* the app, where there's going to be no browser involved. I can't exactly send back a *hold on* reply, and ask the client to poll when the response is ready.

How do I handle this scenario of sending long-working jobs to workers in an API app setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and there are many ways of doing it.

One way would be to have your clients register an endpoint, and then when your background worker is done, you can hit their endpoint.

Comment: Agreed, thank you. Webhooks would work well here. Could you please elaborate on your other "_many ways of doing it._"

Comment: Hmmm...It's hard to say because I don't know exactly what the use case is (and how loosely you want to couple), but other options include polling (which might make sense if you create a client library), or Websockets. Websockets is one of many Pub Sub implementations. Another choice (which I recommend) is Pusher. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern